# Chromium doesn't copy array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, chromium

I'm using Webworker to process array of pixels from Canvas and after returning it back - assign to ImageData array. Firefox works great, but Chromium puts an empty pixel array to the Canvas. Investigation showed that array copying isnt working, resulting array has nulled elements. Array slicing didnt help either, only going through each element with for in helped, but I wonder what is the problem here?

```
imgd = ctx.createImageData(w,h);
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
  imgd.data = e.data; 
  console.log(imgd.data === e.data); // true in FF, false in Chromium  

  img.data = e.data.slice(0); 
  console.log(imgd.data); // correct in FF, empty array in Chromium
};
```

Comment: Are you passing `e` and setting `e.data`, or is this a custom data property of an event object that is unrelated to image data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072295/use-web-worker-to-getimagedata-from-a-file
 This will solve

Answer (score 3):

Chrome:

```
> var e = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').createImageData(10, 10).data;
undefined
> Object.prototype.toString.call(e)
"[object ImageData]"
> e.slice
undefined
```

FX4:

```
>>> var e = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').createImageData(10, 10).data;
undefined
>>> Object.prototype.toString.call(e)
"[object Uint8ClampedArray]"
>>> e.slice
slice()
```

Opera:

```
>>> var e = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').createImageData(10, 10).data;
undefined
>>> Object.prototype.toString.call(e)
"[object CanvasPixelArray]"
>>> e.slice
undefined
```

That tells us what? Well the spec [nowhere states](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#canvaspixelarray) that the pixel data array should have array like methods.

Ergo, only use `.slice` when available, otherwise do a `for loop` copy, oh and also test in more than 2 Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`slice` with just the start parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a Spidermonkey extension. Try specifying the start and end instead:

```
e.data.slice(0, e.data.length)
```

---

**Edit**    [`createImageData`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-createimagedata) returns an [*ImageData* object](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#imagedata) which attributes are read-only. So you can’t change `data`. Use [`createImageData`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-createimagedata) to create an *ImageData* object in your *CanvasRenderingContext2D* from another *ImageData* object:

```
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
    ctx.createImageData(e.data);
};
```

Comment: same result, empty array in Chrome

Comment: @user525032: It seems that the issue is somewhere else. See my edit.

Comment: thanks, so that means FF implementation is not correct (according to specs)

http://jsfiddle.net/rCZjL/1/ (works in FF, doesnt work in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `createImageData()`, I think you want to use [`getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#Getting_the_pixel_data_for_a_context). (That's Mozilla documentation but Chrome also has this method on contexts.)